# My image isn't dowloading to my db table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I have this code in Php to upload images, the thing is that when i insert a picture it will properly get saved in the folder prueba/, but it won't get uploaded to my db_table.

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-add']))
    {
        $name=$_POST['user_name'];

        $images=$_FILES['profile']['name'];
        $tmp_dir=$_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'];
        $imageSize=$_FILES['profile']['size'];

        $upload_dir='prueba/';
        $imgExt=strtolower(pathinfo($images,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        $valid_extensions=array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'pdf');
        $picProfile=rand(1000, 1000000).".".$imgExt;
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir, $upload_dir.$picProfile);
        $stmt=$db_conn->prepare('INSERT INTO restaurantes_resutlado (name, fotos) VALUES (:uname, :upic)');
        $stmt->bindParam(':uname', $name);
        $stmt->bindParam(':upic', $picProfile);
        if($stmt->execute())
        {
            ?>
            <script>
                alert("new record successul");
                window.location.href=('index.php');
            </script>
        <?php
        }else 

        {
            ?>
            <script>
                alert("Error");
                window.location.href=('index.php');
            </script>
        <?php
        }

    }
```

db:

```
Name Type Collation Attributes Null Default Comments Extra
1 id int(11) No None
2 nombre varchar(150) latin1_swedish_ci No None
3 zona varchar(150) latin1_swedish_ci No None
4 precio float No None
5 valoracion float No None
6 comentarios varchar(100) latin1_swedish_ci No None
7 ranking int(1) No None
8 tipo_cocina varchar(100) latin1_swedish_ci No None
9 horario time No None
10 fotos varchar(200) latin1_swedish_ci No None
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="add-form">
            <h1 class="text-center">Please Insert new Item image</h1>
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label>User Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="user_name" class="form-control" required="">
                <label>Picture Profile</label>
                <input type="file" name="profile" class="form-control" required="" accept="*/image">
                <button type="submit" name="btn-add">Add New </button>

            </form>
        </div>
        <hr style="border-top: 2px red solid;">
    </div>  
<!-- end form insert -->
<!-- view form -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="view-form">
        <div class="row">
        <?php 
            $stmt=$db_conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_user ORDER BY id DESC');
                $stmt->execute();
                if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
                {
                    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                    {
                        extract($row);
                        ?>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
            <p><?php echo $username ?></p>
            <img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['picProfile']?>"><br><br>

            <a class="btn btn-info" href="edit_form.php?edit_id=<?php echo $row['id']?>" title="click for edit" onlick="return confirm('Sure to edit this record')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicone-edit"></span>Edit</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="?delete_id=<?php echo $row['id']?>" title="click for delete" onclick="return confirm('Sure to delete this record?')">Delete</a>

            </div>

            <?php 

                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Connection:

```
<?php
// Database configuration
$dbHost     = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "root";
$dbName     = "restaurantes";

// Create database connection
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

// Check connection
if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
}
?>
```

Comment: What does it mean `won't get uploaded`? What do you expect to see in a table and what do you have?

Comment: post the connection, the HTML for this and the schema

Comment: you have too many unclosed questions

Comment: @u_mulder I mean that in the db table it won't make a new row with the data that im uploading

Comment: Check your servers error log. You can also add some error logging for your insert statement to see what actually happens. Here's how: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i posed what you asked

Comment: you posted that in the answers area rather than an edit https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47846921/edit to which you need to delete it from the answers area, it's reserved for solutions only.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson there are no server logs on the console

Comment: Server logs are on the _server_, not in the console (which only shows you _client_ logs).

Comment: You seem to be mixing MySQLi and PDO syntax. `$pdo->bindParam()` and `$mysqli->bind_param()`. Those two API's are not interchangeable. You are also creating the connection `$db` and are using `$db_conn` in your scripts. Stick to one api and check the manual for the correct usage.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson there is no error log on the txt file

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner ok i edit it.

Comment: What text file? You do have a web server, right? That web server should have some error log. If you can't see any errors, make sure that you have `error_reporting()` turned on in the beginning of your script. I would also advice you to display errors while you're developing with `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in the beginning as well.

Comment: yeah, you're mixing different apis, and you should have posted that right away;  you can't do that.

Comment: you're also using the wrong variable for the connection/query.

Comment: There's too many errors here. You need to restart and check the manual for the correct usage of the classes/api's your using.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'm using  a local host db with mamp, ive change the $db_conn with $db but i don't find the $mysqli that i inserted by error.. is it the "move_uploaded_file"?

Comment: Again, you're mixing PDO and MySQLi API's. The are _not_ interchangeable. Please read the manual.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks it's working now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing different mysql apis with mysqli_ and PDO, you can't do that as they do not intermix.

The connection variable also (theoretically) do not match.

You need to use a PDO connection to go along with the PDO query.

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Example connection from the manual:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```

and use the same variable for it in the query. You're using `$db` so match that with the connection also.

**Note:** You're also using the wrong column name being `name` in VALUES. Since I don't know Spanish (seems to be), you will need to use the one that corresponds to it. You may have meant to use `nombre`.

Use (proper) error handling also:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Example of PDO error handling from the manual:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

You are also using GET methods, so make sure that those pan out.

Use a prepared statement also. It will help safeguard against a potential SQL injection.

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @Whoiscoo you're welcome. Give that a whirl, check for errors and if something doesn't work out, see what the error(s) is (are), Google those and you will most likely be able to fix it. Debugging and learning how to properly interpret/understand error messages is essential during development but most importantly, the learning and knowledge you would have gained.

Comment: thanks, it is working now!